# Java Server listen to Client and at the same time take in user input and sent over to client

Tags: java, udp, client-server

Im trying to establish a chat room kind of scenario where the server will keep listening for any datapacket from a client, while at the same time be able to detect if the server has typed anything to send over to the client

Here is what i've done so far but i cant think of a correct way to do it because right now my code will get stuck waiting for an input at readLine()

```
for(;;){
    String input=null;
    input = inFromUser.readLine();
    if (input.equals("exit")){
        break;
    }else if (!input.equals(null)){
        byte[] newText = input.getBytes();
        sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(newText, newText.length, IPAddress, 9876);      
        serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
        System.out.println("TO CLIENT(BOB): "+ new String(newText));
    }else{
        receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        realSentence = Arrays.copyOf(receivePacket.getData(), receivePacket.getLength());
        String fromHost = new String(realSentence);
        System.out.println("FROM CLIENT(BOB): " + fromHost);
    }
}
```

So i  would like to know is there anyway to listen for datagram and at the same time be able to read in words typed on the terminal and send to client

Answer (score 0):

You will want a multi-threaded program.  one thread for listening for incoming packets, and another
that waits for the user to type things.